# Estou a obter este erro Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

Tudo estava a funcionar, mas depois de alguns tempos comecei a receber constantemente este erro:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

O servidor mysql parece estar constantemente a cair.
Depois eu reinicio e ele ao fim de algum tempo cai novamente.

Comment: Testou se o servidor MySQL está em execução?

Comment: Ele tinha caido, mas parece estar sempre caindo

Comment: Ele não estava em execução,ai reiniciei. Parece que algo está a fazer ele constantemente cair

Comment: Precisa checar se não tem corrupção em alguma tabela ou base de dados. Seria o caso de você [edit] a pergunta e por o máximo de detalhes possíveis, pois como está, precisariamos fazer diversas perguntas aqui nos comentários até conseguirmos entender o problema. Se você puder complementar a pergunta com tudo que já testou e tentou, seria bom. Aqui tem umas dicas: [Ask]

Comment: Eu reinicie tudo e parece estar a funcionar, mas eu ja tinha feito antes então eu imagino que dentro de algum tempo isto vai voltar a cair novamente

Comment: Amadeu, sua aplicação esta encerrando as conexões com o MySQL após usa-las? Isso pode ser limite de conexão.

Comment: Como você faz a conexão??? LocalHost ou 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Ok o que eu fiz foi aumentar a memória ram e troquei o processador para um mais rápido e pronto isso funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok o que eu fiz foi aumentar a memória ram e troquei o processador para um mais rápido e pronto isso funcionou. Não tive mais nenhum problema depois destas alterações.